# How can the root password on FreeBSD 9.1 be changed for the system for the purposes of root logins?

Tags: unix, xen, freebsd, password, bsd

I've never encountered this before when using FreeBSD, but I recently got a new BSD VPS, and when I logged in as a wheel user and su to root, I used "passwd" to change the root password, but this only appears to have changed the password locally (works for su, but not ssh; I can ssh with the default password); I cannot login as root using this password.

I made sure root login was enabled in /etc/ssh/sshd_config, and from the reading I did on the matter, as well as consulting the man page, there can be different types (for different authentication methods) of passwords (though I may have misunderstood).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both the console and ssh login are passed through PAM by default, which by default uses the "unix" method of password verification (on FreeBSD is uses a database version od the passwd.master file). In your case I think you can assume that console and ssh have different configurations in PAM. Check `/etc/pam.d/sshd`, the default configuration of the auth, account, and password sections ends with `pam_unix.so`... the `/etc/pam.d/login` file should look similar (though by default the sshd file has more options).

Comment: Thanks. When the VPS was provisioned, it seems, the /etc/pam.d/login and sshd files were jumbled and partially unreadable; I was able to recreate them and the password changes and changed in sshd_config were applicable.